# Set the Log file name dynamically in app.config

Tags: tracelistener

I am writing a simple app where i define my trace listener in the app.config.  have defined it as below.

```
<system.diagnostics>
      <switches>
        <add name="TraceSwitchLevel" value="4"/>
      </switches>
      <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
        <listeners>
          <add name="logFileListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="fileNameTemplate='TextWriterLog-{1:MMM-yy}.log'" />
          <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>
      </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
```

the purpose is for the log/trace file to be different every time the app is run. However I am getting the following exception when i try to write to the trace listener using trace.writeline method. 
{"The given path's format is not supported."}
What am i doing wrong here? How can i achieve this?

Comment: The above will create, at best, a file named "fileNameTemplate='TextWriterLog-.log'" after you remove the {1:MMM-yy} part. There is no expansion of the file. This can't be accomplished in config alone, you'll have to create a derived TextWriterTraceListener.